# How to map XMLType with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

How to persist XMLType column via JPA/Hibernate? As per oracle documentation, there are two ways in declaring storage clause for XMLType. They are, LOB and Object-Relational. I dont want to go with LOB. I have schema and register into database. I have not have example on how to design my Entity for XMLType. Does any one know please share it?

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me (JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.1.0):

- Create the field in the entity as a String.
- Use the @ColumnTransformer annotation from Hibernate to define how to read and write from the column.
- Set the columnDefinition in @Column as "XMLType"

  @ColumnTransformer(read = "to_clob(columnName)", write = "?")
  @Column(name = "COLUMN_NAME", columnDefinition = "XMLType")
  private String columnName;

Comment: This fails if over 4,000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom `UserType` (Hibernate extension). The blog post [Hibernate with Oracle XmlType](http://mosisa.wordpress.com/2008/07/14/hibernate-with-oracle-xmltype/) provides an implementation that you might reuse. Then, declare your custom `UserType` with the [`Type`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794) annotation.

Comment: Thanks. But I got this below SQL exception when I try to persist through JPA entitymanager. I have done exactly what you provided in your blogs
>created hibernate usertype class
>entity pointing to @Type("HibernateXMLType")
>Document as field

SQL Exception
-------------
java.sql.SQLException: Could not convert Document to String for storage

Comment: @Moorthy: Please update your question with the problem, it's unreadable in the comment box.

Comment: The oracle xml parser xmlparserv2.jar is causing the issue. If I remove it, HibernateXMLType class throws the below exception from the line
 xmlType = XMLType.createXML(st.getConnection(),..)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xml/parser/v2/XMLParseException
 at com.tutorial.hibernate.HibernateXMLType.nullSafeSet(HibernateXMLType.java:112)

I know this parser conflict with javax.xml..parser

Please throw some light on this how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The custom java class HibernateXMLType works fine for CLOB.