# XMLType - SQL state [99999]; error code [31011]; could not update:

Tags: java

[How to map XMLType with JPA/Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064330/how-to-map-xmltype-with-jpa-hibernate)

I have done XMLType mappings with Hibernate @Type with the help of above URL.

It works fine when I persist with the data type HibernateXmlType. It has results however, it throws below exception:

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [update BTI_DBA.SAMPLE_XMLINSTRUCTIONS set INSTRUCTION_XML=? where INSTRUCTION_ID=?]; SQL state [99999]; error code [31011]; could not update: [com.tutorial.model.SampleXmlInstructions#4871852354547076634]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [com.tutorial.model.SampleXmlInstructions#4871852354547076634]
.........
.........
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00209: PI names starting with XML are reserved
Error at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your input has one and only one element of the form...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

at the top of your document.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it. I dont know how it gets entered twice the prologs.