# How can I insert an XML document in PostgreSQL in Java?

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, jdbc

I have a table in Postgresql

```
DROP TABLE xml_docs;
CREATE TABLE xml_docs(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
cad_number character(50),
gkuzu_name character(50),
gkuzu xml,
rreq_name character(50),
rreq xml
)
```

I use JDBC for data base connection. And i want to insert whole xml document in table.
How can i make this?

**UPDATE**

Okey. i try

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO xml_docs(cad_number,gkuzu_name,gkuzu,rreq_name,rreq) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
  PreparedStatement stmt = ce.prepareStatement(sql);
  stmt.setString(1, "11:33:5464563");
  stmt.setString(2, xml_gkuzu.getName());
  stmt.setString(3, xml_gkuzu.toString());
  stmt.setString(4, xml_rreq.getName());
  stmt.setString(5, xml_rreq.toString());
  stmt.executeQuery();
ce.close();
  se.close();
```

and get exeption

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "gkuzu" is of type xml but expression is of type character varying
Подсказка: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

Whats wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

When i try do this

```
 String sql1 = "INSERT INTO xml_docs(cad_number,gkuzu_name,gkuzu,rreq_name,rreq) VALUES(11335464563,"+xml_gkuzu.getName()+",XMLPARSE("+xml_gkuzu.toString()+"),"+xml_rreq.getName()+",XMLPARSE("+xml_rreq.toString()+"))";
```

i get exeption

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "bf48e000b0"
```

Comment: useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064330/how-to-map-xmltype-with-jpa-hibernate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try this:

First convert your XML to a Java String.
Then create an insert statement und use the XMLPARSE method of PostgreSQL to convert your value to the xml type of PostgreSQL:

```
INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (1, XMLPARSE('<foo><bar>Hello</bar></foo>'));
```

See: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support

**UPDATE:**

Java code example:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (?, XMLPARSE(?))";
[...]
stmt.setString(2, "<foo>Hello World!</foo>");
```

This should create this statement:

```
INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (1, XMLPARSE('<foo>Hello World!</foo>'));
```

Comment: `stmt.setString(3, "XMLPARSE("+xml_gkuzu.toString()+")"); ` this construction give same exeption.

Comment: If you use "stmt.setString()" your second parameter will be inserted as a varchar value. Your statement looks then like this: "INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (1, 'XMLPARSE(<foo></foo>)'". But it must be: "INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (1, XMLPARSE('<foo></foo>')". (Quotes)

Comment: Now i make like in your example but get exeption. Look at UPADATE 2 please.

Comment: After trying code from your UPDATE i get exeption `Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"`

Comment: Anywhere in your final sql statement must be "$3". But I don't know where. Contains your xml string "$3"?

Comment: No they didnt. I think i work with xml wrong. I do this `File xml_rreq = new File("RREQ_ceec91b1-f15b-49e5-ae4c-72bf48e000b0.xml");`. Its correct?

Comment: If you use Apache Commons IO, you can use this: [link](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)). Or you do it like this: [link](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/java-read-file-string)

Comment: For version 9.0 and greater `XMLPARSE` ==> `XML`.

Comment: To clarify comment by Adam Gent, the standard way to produce a value of type `xml` from character data is to use the function `XMLPARSE ( { DOCUMENT | CONTENT } value)`. Postgres adds its own  Postgre-specific syntaxes: `xml '<foo>bar</foo>'` and `'<foo>bar</foo>'::xml`. [See doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html).

Answer (score 8):

Instead of rewriting the insert statement using PostgreSQL-proprietary syntax, you could use [JDBC 4 SQLXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html):

```
String xml = xml_gkuzu.toString();

SQLXML sqlxml = connection.createSQLXML();
sqlxml.setString(xml);
stmt.setSQLXML(3, sqlxml);
```

Comment: By far the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Though postgres has native `XML Data type`, from java end, You can handle with Plain strings.
You can convert your xml document to String and insert, It should work.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at your error, You need to pass an additional variable to the server through driver URL.

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?stringtype=unspecified
or
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=user&password=pass&stringtype=unspecified
```

The extra param `stringtype=unspecified` will remove the type check for the input strings.

Comment: Maybe i do something wrong but `System.out.println(xml_rreq.toString());` give filename. How to take xml document from file?

Comment: `File file = new File("c:\\yourfile.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);`

Comment: You can search on google for how to convert `file -> xml document` or `file -> inputstream -> string` for more help.

Comment: Thank you so much, yours is the only solution that helped me. If I would read this answer for the first time I landed this page it would save me hours

Answer (score 3):

An update to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051311/318174) if you do not have Postgres built with libxml support:

Java code example:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (?, XML(?))";
[...]
stmt.setString(2, "<foo>Hello World!</foo>");
```

This should create this statement:

```
INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (1, XML('<foo>Hello World!</foo>'));
```

Thus for version 9.0 and greater you may want to switch `XMLPARSE` ==> `XML`. Otherwise you will need special support for `XMLPARSE`

[From Postgres Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-xml.html):

> The function-like expressions xmlparse and xmlserialize for converting to and from type xml are not repeated here. Use of most of these functions requires the installation to have been built with configure --with-libxml.