# How can I store XML data?

Tags: xml, postgresql, jooq

I saw [How can I insert an XML document in PostgreSQL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050945/how-can-i-insert-xml-document-in-postgresql-with-java) but I was wondering if jOOQ offers another solution to this kind of problem.

At the moment I don't see another method as to write something like

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO xml_docs(id, gkuzu) VALUES (?, XMLPARSE(?))";
```

and execute it with jOOQ

```java
this.ctx.execute(sql);
```

but is there another option for more complex statements where I can also write e.g.

```java
StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();

// ..

this.ctx.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
    .set(MY_TABLE.NAME, name)
    // ..
    .set(MY_TABLE.DESCRIPTION_XML, xml.toString());
```

or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ 3.7 doesn't support XML (or JSON, etc.) types out of the box, but indeed, jOOQ helps you abstract the XML data type by implementing your custom data type binding. There's an example for JSON and PostgreSQL in the manual. You can adapt that easily for XML:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings

Essentially, you'll need to implement [`org.jooq.Binding<Object, YourXMLRepresentation>`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Binding.html), and then configure the code generator to apply this binding either to all `XML` type columns, or to columns of a specific name pattern:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings

Comment: Okay, I see :) I've noticed in the generated code that it builds a map with `Object` as values type. Then I realized that this might be done with a `Converter`. Thanks Lukas!

Comment: @displayname: A converter will be insufficient for this case, as you have to specify on a JDBC level, how to bind XML variables (e.g. by generating `XMLPARSE(?)` or `?::xml`). This can be done with a `Binding` only

Comment: Ah sorry, got that wrong. Was on my way to work as I was reading your answer. Thanks for pointing that out :D