# Save JPA entity model with XML column in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

Postgres supports `xml` as is datatype for a column.
Hence I have a model that goes like this

```
@Entity
class StorageOfXml {
    @Id
    String id;

    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition="xml")
    String myXml;
}
```

When I try to persist the model using entity manager, it gives me an error

```
StorageOfXml s = new StorageOfXml()
s.setId("sample");
s.setMyXml("<foo><bar></bar></foo>");

entityManager.persist(s)
```

Error is

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "myXml" is of type xml but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I notice that I need to cast the string to an xml format. However, I don't know where and how to cast it. How should I be able to persist and fetch this?

Comment: hey, I'm not using Hibernate and Oracle, so this is a pure JPA and Postgres thing

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Without using hibernate or jaxb and if you really really want to save "myXml" as pg xml type, one solution would be to use XMLPARSE on a statement as the accepted answer in this post suggests: [How can I insert an XML document in PostgreSQL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050945/how-can-i-insert-an-xml-document-in-postgresql-in-java)

Comment: Is there something with JAXB that can do this? I am open to JAXB solutions. anyway I used and saw that link already but I'm trying to keep away from creating prepared statements

Comment: @bumblebeen did you find a way to do this in the end?